# Queue job for multiple email id not working

Tags: laravel, email, task-queue

I try to send multiple email in queue laravel but its not working working single in single email, in my controller

```
$mail_id = Email::select('email')->whereNotNull('news')->get();
        $emailid = [];
        foreach($mail_id as $key => $value){
            $emailid[] = $value->email;
        }
         $email = $tags = implode(',', $emailid);
        $details = [
            'emails' => $email,
            'subject' => 'We add New News plese vist our news page and view there <a href="https://example.com/news">News</a>'
        ];
        
        $job = (new \App\Jobs\SendEmailQueueJob($details))->delay(now()->addSeconds(2)); 

        $send_job = dispatch($job);
```

and my SendEmailQueueJob file lclass SendEmailQueueJob implements ShouldQueue

```
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
   
    protected $details;
    public $timeout = 7200; // 2hr

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
      
        $input[] = $this->details['emails'];
        $email = new SendNewsAlert();
            Mail::to($value->email)->send($input);
       
      

    }
}
```

in single email its working fine but pass it show error in error log file

```
[2023-04-27 15:55:25] local.ERROR: Undefined array key "emaildata" {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key \"emaildata\" at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\app\\Jobs\\SendEmailQueueJob.php:36)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions.php(250): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 36)
```

why it's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are passing the email addresses as a string separated by commas. Try passing it as an array. So modify your `handle` method like:

```php
public function handle()
{
    $emails = explode(',', $this->details['emails']);

    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        Mail::to($email)->send(new SendNewsAlert());
    }
}
```